# Is there a way to make rtorrent write bytes "on-the-go" in the disk?

Tags: node.js, bittorrent, torrent, libtorrent, utorrent

Hello stackoverflow users,

I am having a bit of trouble getting something to work.

> **What I want to accomplish?**
> I want to read bytes (and write them somewhere) while the file is downloading in rtorrent,

First of all, I have rtorrent connected to flood. In my nodejs app I have an interval to get the percentage of files downloaded in rtorrent.
Based on the percentage I read "x" bytes from the file it's downloading through rtorrent and writing to user.
However, after diving deep into rtorrent writing to disk, I've discovered that rtorrent doesn't write to disk "on-the-go", which means my app won't work.

My question is, is there a way I can make rtorrent write the bytes directly on the disk and not after a certain period ( which I don't know the period, it's just random after many many tests ) ?

Comment: @AnonCoward that doesn't happen. I have a code that compares bytes from the file that is downloading on rTorrent and the one that is already downloaded. While comparing it seems it's not always writing data right after the data is transferred. And since I read the bytes from the file downloading with rTorrent, some of the bytes that I read as the download goes, becomes corrupted..

Comment: @AnonCoward the script has an interval and each 2 seconds it checks the bytes written from different percentage, for example 0 to 20%. Flood api gives me the current percentage of the torrent that's downloading in rTorrent and by that I compare.Let's say the flood api gives me percentage 30%, but when I compare the bytes (sha256 hashed buffer) from 0 to 20% (of the file that's downloading) they are not the same sha256 as the file that I have already downloaded (fully)

Comment: From the docs, the Flood API doesn't seem to have that API to know which parts have been downloaded, do you know which one does that, please? Also I'm using sequential download.

Comment: IO behavior is very implementation-dependent and not a general property of bittorrent. You might want to ask on their forums instead.

Comment: @AnonCoward do you have any idea? I apply sequential download to files.. is there a way to check when I should read and write the bytes, this way I don't get empty bytes, because rtorrent didn't write the bytes same as the percentage is telling?